# Transparency headache

Tags: css

I just made an image to give you a visual example for understanding my question.

[image: a visual example related to my question]

[html example (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/TgWMH/1/)

As you can see, I have an active arrow whose purpose is to circulate along the content columns. However, I want the transparency from the header's background, and not from the content when deleting my white background.

Is there any trick to burn through my content background to reach the background to my header?

I made an extra image for a better view:

[image: updated visual example]

Note: I use patterns as background, not solid colors.

Comment: any live url or testing url ?

Comment: It's now added in my question

Comment: is your header bg is fixed or not ?

Comment: try this one may be .. you will get your output http://jsfiddle.net/TgWMH/10/

Comment: Thank you for taking a look, but I dont see any changes?

Answer (score 4):

My initial thought is a background on the content area with a transparent triangle bitten out of it. <s>Then apply a negative margin to the content</s> Then set the content's position to `relative` and set it's `top` property to a negative amount and set the bottom padding of the header to the same amount.

Something similar to this? http://jsfiddle.net/sT53s/

Comment: Good thinking, I also came that far. But what if you have the columns centered in a wrapper 100% width wrapper? I've added up a live example in my question.

Comment: Almost there! I want the side bars also at the same height and same background as the columns, so it won't stick out like you have it now.

Comment: @Jonathan Yeah I had a quick go at getting the sidebars to show but I'm at work so shouldn't really be working on other people's problems! That's as much as I have time for, good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You can play with css3 rotate property check this http://jsfiddle.net/TgWMH/18/

**HTML**

```
<div class="arrow three"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.arrow.three:after {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    background: url("http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2665/4170671240_a90769d747.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    content: "";
    height: 200px;
    left: -14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
.arrow.three {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -51px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: @SACHIN see OP tags he define CSS3 which means he is open for CSS3 answer. That's why my answer it related to CSS3

Comment: ya i undstnd bt still we should keep browser compatibility in mind alteast in ie9.

Comment: That's not a reason for downvote. for IE9 you can use -ms-transform

Comment: I see a visible diamond with a background not correctly displayed

Comment: can you add the screenshot ? even @sandeep know this thing

Comment: @Jonathan you can adjust according to your requirement

Comment: deadly answer.upvote :-) still ie8 .. but we can compromize for that :-)

Comment: I've added up a new image to give you a better view

Comment: @ sandeep I can't do anything with a diamond

Answer (score 1):

### CSS3 Multi-background Version

As long as your content region is always going to have a solid background colour you could use the following modification:

```
.header {
  height: 200px;
  background: url("http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2665/4170671240_a90769d747.jpg") fixed;
}
```

By adding `fixed` you make sure that where ever else that background image is used, it should align correctly. Then there is this modification:

```
.arrow2 {
  margin-top: -2px;
  width: 111px;
  height: 56px;
  background: url("http://s17.postimage.org/5iq6rsz0b/arrow2.png") no-repeat 0 0,
    url("http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2665/4170671240_a90769d747.jpg") fixed;
}
```

Then all you need to do is reverse your arrow2.png so that the arrow area itself is transparent and the outside part of the arrow contains your content's background color.

*Obviously this will only work for browsers that support multiple backgrounds.*

### CSS2 Single-background Version

Thinking about it, as my brain is being rather slow today... there is no reason to *have* to use multiple-backgrounds. You could just have your arrow markup like so:

```
<div class="arrow2">
  <div class="arrow-inner"></div>
</div>
```

And then apply the `4170671240_a90769d747.jpg` fixed background to .arrow2, but apply your actual `arrow2.png` background to .arrow-inner. This way you don't have to make any exceptions for older browsers as it should just work.

```
.arrow2 {
  margin-top: -2px;
  width: 111px;
  height: 56px;
  background: url("http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2665/4170671240_a90769d747.jpg") fixed;
}

.arrow-inner {
  width: 111px;
  height: 56px;
  background: url("http://s17.postimage.org/5iq6rsz0b/arrow2.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

*arrow2.png still needs to be inverted for this to work - so that the arrow area is transparent and the outside not*

Comment: Thanks, that could be a solution with a solid background! But since I have a pattern background, this will not do. I've edited the code with yours: http://jsfiddle.net/TgWMH/24/

Comment: @Jonathan - ah in that case then the first solution by MrMisterMan is your best bet :) Sandeep's solution is novel, but I would say it has more chances of going wrong (or pixelating the background image, like it does for me).

Answer (score -1):

this is a fairly old post but checkout this code pen that solves the problem with two pseudo elements. It's a sass mixin and you can configure it for every edge, width and triangle position you like. http://codepen.io/gionkunz/pen/ihgwH